# turn osm2po vertex table restrictions column into turn cost for shooting star pgrouting?

Tags: pgrouting, osm2po

i found this thread

[Does OSM2PO take into consideration turn restrictions?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41393/does-osm2po-take-into-consideration-turn-restrictions)

but im kind of new to sql and database so me, making my own query or sp to achieve the above suggestion by myself is kind of far from reality. can somebody help me please? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

osm2po takes most of osm's turn restrictions into account. Nevertheless, I assume you are looking for some support for pgRouting's ShootingStar. But this has not been implemented by anyone, yet.